# separate legend in groups with facet_wrap ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, facet-wrap

Please find a reprex below but this is what I currently have:

[image]

I don't need to have a separate legend for each of the plots but I would like the legend to be divided by the facets. It can just be by having a separate title:

Cash flow indicator ratios

- Ratio xx
- Ratio yy
- Ratio zz

Growth ratios

- Ratio aa
- Ratio bb
- Ratio cc

...

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to do that?

Thank you!!

**REPREX:**

```
mtcars$names <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars <- mtcars %>%
   mutate(group = case_when(gear == 3 ~ "A", 
                            gear == 4 ~ "B", 
                            gear == 5 ~ "C"))

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = names, group =group)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point()+
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=1))+
  facet_wrap(~ group)
```

I would like to have the legend divided in Groups A, B, C.

Comment: without a reproducible example it is almost impossible to help you.  If your real data is to large or complex, try using a public dataset (such as `mtcars`) to illustrate your issue.

Comment: Just added one.

Comment: Something is wrong. It is `mtcars` and you need to specify `mpg` and `disp` in `aes`

Comment: Please check now!

Comment: Check out this thread, which is basically a dupe. However, not with accepted answer, so won't mark it as a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064662/how-can-i-organize-my-legend-into-subgroups

Comment: Or this thread - you can create a fake legend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064845/add-annotation-and-segments-to-groups-of-legend-elements/49077005#49077005